# Inside transparent arrow with drop shadow

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website and my navigation need a transparent arrow and see the drop shadow below the `div`.

I need a solution in pure HTML/CSS (no JavaScript).

**Desired result :**

---

[image: Desired result]

---

**Here's what I tried** (I put the triangle in red to see it, if a put transparent nothing is shown)

```
.box {
    position:relative;
    display:block; 
    height:100px; 
    width:100%;    
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}

.box:after {
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    border: 15px solid;
    margin-left: -15px;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    left:50%;
    border-color:transparent transparent red transparent;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L105/qxrHq/1/)

Comment: Is setting the color of the triangle to the same shade/alpha of gray as the drop shadow not the correct result for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two pseudo-elements and [**transforms**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform).

## [*demo*](http://jsfiddle.net/7DpgT/2/)

Relevant CSS:

```
.box:before, .box:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 50%; height: 1em;
    transform-origin: 100% 0;
    transform: skewX(-45deg);
    background: inherit;
}

.box:after {
    right: 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: skewX(45deg);
}
```

[Support is pretty good](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d). Browsers that support `box-shadow` support 2D transforms as well.

Comment: Hey, you are back ! I like your posts and I was missing  them !